# Let $G$ be a group, $H\le G$. Define $X=\cup_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}.$ Prove $X=G$ when $[G:H]<\infty$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$. Define $$X = \bigcup_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}.$$ I want to prove that $X=G$ when $[G:H] < \infty$.

I had couple of observations:

1. $g_1 H g_1^{-1} = g_2 H g_2^{-1} \iff g_1 N_G(H) = g_2 N_G(H)$. Thus, the number of different subgroups $g H g^{-1}$ as $g$ varies is $[G: N_G(H)]$.
2. Since all $g H g^{-1}$ contain $1_G$, they are not disjoint.

Then I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the opposite is true. A group is never the union of the conjugates of a proper subgroup.

Comment: I proved that if $G$ is finite then $X \neq G$.

Comment: @TokenToucan It would be possible for infinite groups. See Remark 6.9 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is wrong. If $H$ is normal then $X=H$ (this always happens if the index is 2).

Comment: Your claim is obvious. Any counter-example to above statement?

Comment: @MaximUlyanov: Could you elaborate? My answer shows that what you are trying to prove is false if $H$ is normal. In fact it not easy to find a group and a subgroup for which it is true. There are examples but infinite examples are very hard to construct.

Comment: I am so tired. You are right, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Since as you wrote $X\ne G$ for finite groups, the same is true for any infinite group $G$ and any subgroup $H$ of finite index. Indeed, $H$ contains a normal subgroup $N$ of finite index and if $X=G$ then the same is true for the finite group $G/N$ and its proper subgroup $H/N$. If the index is not assumed to be finite then there are examples where $X=G$. You can find some of them in the book by Olshanskii "Geometry of defining relations in groups".